# IE 8 and 7 incredibly slow load time

Tags: internet-explorer

I am new to web development and my pages are loading incredibly slow in IE 8 and 7. What would you suggest I do to debug these problems?

Comment: What are the pages written in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.In all cases you can improve speed by, using image sprites, remove whitespace from code, optcode caching, and using a CDN.

It also depends on what you are using to write your pages

HTML - I don't think this is a problem, HTML code just gets read and displayed by the broswer.

PHP - If you are using PHP then it may be the time for browser to parse your code into HTML. If this is the case I would recommend thoroughly checking your markup and seeing how you can "neaten" the code per se.

ASP - Same applies here really

Wordpress - If you are using wordpress as a management system, then your pages will be in PHP but also there is a plugin called W3C Total Cache, this can optimally improve web loading times.

Comment: The browser doesn't parse PHP or ASP, the server does, so the browser that's being used shouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).